# The GCC source code directory(.c files)

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Where is the directory normally located? For example, when you compile headers that have function prototypes which are linked to the GCC source library? I ask because I just downloaded slab.c which has the kmalloc function(got a link error from compiling another header so now I have a source code file that implements it).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You don't compile headers, you include them. There is no `slab.c` in the GCC source tree, and no `kmalloc` function in GCC, they're part of the Linux kernel, not GCC.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to compile the kernel or a kernel module.  Doing that is different from compiling normal programs.  There are a lot of guides available for compiling for the kernel, you should find one and then ask questions about it....

Answer (score 1):

This:-

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

command is used by gcc to check for headers file.

Comment: While true, that doesn't have anything to do with where GCC's `.c` source files live, or anything to do with the Linux kernel's `slab.c` source file.

Comment: @JonathanWakely:- I agree. To be very true I have just guessed what OP may be looking for. Not very sure and keeping my fingers crossed for some downvotes too!!!

Comment: hehe, yes, I think we're all guessing! :-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely:- Yes although now I have voted to close the question. Dont know if thats right or not!!!